# Java Add Escape Sequence to String

Tags: java, escaping, sequence, truncate

Say for example, that I have a method that returns the string \"ex\". Obviously, this will be printed out as "ex"

How can I make a method that allows me to print \"ex\" without the escape sequences cut out?
I need to create or use another method to do so, as I have no access to the original method that returns the string.

The reason I'm doing this is because I am trying to create a JSON representation to parse with a json parser. With my current code, I am getting

{example:[{"url":""ex""}]} along with all the other special characters that individually need an escape character in order for it to parse properly.

Comment: Your first sentence makes no sense to me.  If a method returns `\"ex\"` then that's exactly what will be printed if you print its return value.

Answer (score 2):

use this statement:

```
return "\\\"ex\"\\";
```

this will be printed:\"ex"\
or:

```
return "\\ex\\"
```

this will be printed:\ex\

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to worry about the `/` You can do something like

```
System.out.println("http://google.com");
```

This will work fine as `/` is not a special character in java.